# ionic app running on an iOS can not access API end points on aws ec2. Desktop version of the same app does. Can you help ? Is this a cors issue?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ionic-framework, ionic4

i have an app that uses ionic and cordova plugin.

Backend: MongoDB, Express & NodeJS. Backend code is hosted on AWS EC2.

Front end: Ionic and Angular (ionic CLI 5.4.16). Code is executed either on the desktop (ionic serve) or on iOS device (ionic cordova build ios --prod)

While testing the app on desktop, I am able to connect to aws hosted endpoint (user/login) and execute corresponding workflows.

However, when I run the same app code from the iOS device no connection with the endpoint is established and i get http error code 0.

**Configuration**:

- ionic frontend url (on desktop): localhost:8100

  server url: aws-instance-url/api endpoint

  reverse proxy using nginx on serve side: localhost:4443

  ssl certificate and key have been rightly configured for https
  requests and are working

**Cors settings**

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

const whiteList = [
                   'http://localhost:8100',
                   'ionic://localhost:8100',
                   'ionic://*.*,
                   'file://*.*   
                 ];

var corsOptionsDelegate = (req, callback) => {
  var corsOptions;
  if (whiteList.indexOf(req.header('Origin')) !== -1) {
    console.log("origin in whiteList");
    corsOptions = { origin: true };
  }
  else {
    console.log("origin NOT in whiteList");
    corsOptions =  { origin: false };
  }
  callback(null, corsOptions);
};

exports.cors = cors();
exports.corsWithOptions = cors(corsOptionsDelegate);
```

Note - when accessing through the iOS device the code never flows into corsOptionsDelegate if/else loop. However, when accessed through the desktop origin is found in the whitelist..

Is this CORS issues ? Has anyone tried to access api endpoints via iOS device successfully ?

Appreciate your help...

Comment: I think you are running into CORS error. I have accessed API endpoints via Android device, using a capacitor plugin: https://github.com/capacitor-community/http But your app doesn't run on top of capacitor, right? It runs on top of cordova, so check out this doc: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/

Comment: Thanks for your response and the links. Yes, i am not using capacitor but cordova. I did check native http option as well. Problem is,  I have used angular http everywhere in my code  across my all of my services, and the amount of regression/refactoring needed to change to ionic native http is huge. Is there any other way by which I could access API endpoints from my device

Comment: Maybe to enable CORS in the backend. Proxy used for avoiding CORS error doesn't work for mobile devices, only for browser (and maybe desktop, since your app works fine in desktop).